# IOS Customkeyboard : How to set left side Constrain to customkeyboard?

Tags: ios, custom-keyboard

I am trying to implement custom keyboard for iphone 6 and 6+ users so for that i need to set constrain for left and right side keyboard . how can i set this type of constrain in my keyboard ? need suggetion please .
Note:- In example image constrain are set on Keyboard layout. how can i do this ? 
     [image: Lest side constrain in Keyboard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set Trailing space of p or The back arrow or button 123 to superview then you get the right constrain and and for Top space constraint set q or others Top sapce constraints to superview

Comment: whaaa. let me try and  i want to set left side constrain . so, how can i set it ? which i need to set on q , a, and other button like t,f,g or etc ?

Comment: @BadalShah you need to set 1) Leading space of q to container view and trailing space of p to container view 2)Set horizontal spacing between Q-W, W-E, E-R, R-T, T-Y, Y-U, U-I, I-O, O-P and also with equal width constraints by which they all share equal space of the keyboard total width 3)set g to centre horizontal to container view 4)set horizontal spacing of second row as we did in the first row 5)Set equal width constraints of all the second row button with any of the first row button

Comment: thanks @Vivek Patel  this worked for me . please look at this question if you have any idea help me please . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872331/ios-customkeyboard-getting-wrong-size-in-landscape-mode?noredirect=1#comment51664781_31872331